# Meson default c-args and buildtype=plain cfg option

Tags: arguments, cross-compiling, ninja, meson-build

I have a project with some sub-projects,
I have configured with the following commands

**meson project/builddir --cross-file qnx7.meson --buildtype=plain**

If I have understood well the use of buildtype=plain,
I should not find in ARGS the default c flags both in the main project and also in the sub-projects ones.

But then when I go to look at the **build.ninja** file I got the unwanted default **cflags**.

Any idea how to solve this issue?
The meson version is
**meson -v
0.55.3**

Comment: It would be helpful to know what flags you're talking about, and what language(s) you're using. Meson injects a few options based on other options, `b_colorout` will add options like `-fcolor-output=always`, and it always adds largefile support, regardless of any options set.

Comment: the option is OFFSET_BITS=64  and the compiler 
/opt/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/ntox86_64-gcc,
I suggest to add a build flag to meson in order to give the possibility to avoid any default flags.

BR

Comment: At the moment to solve this issue I have chosen a quick and dirty solution 
adding a script to be executed after meson build in order to remove/replace from build.ninja the unwanted flags


:

# ======
# Target post-build to override unwanted meson flags
# ======
run_target('postBuild',
  command : ['./postBuild.sh', meson.current_build_dir()])